# Send a message with Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a discord bot, but I can't quite understand Discord.js.
My code looks like this:

```js
client.on('message', function(message) {
 if (message.content === 'ping') {
  client.message.send(author, 'pong');
 }
});
```

And the problem is that I can't quite understand how to send a message.

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: Have you read through the documentation?

Comment: is that if statement true at any point? Please try to use `console.log("test")` and put it inside the if statement and check the console for the output

Comment: I've runned through the documentation

Comment: @MártonKissik Do not use that link as it contains outdated info. Use https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome . You send a message using `message.channel.send("Something")`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The send code has been changed again. Both the items in the question as well as in the answers are all outdated. For version 12, below will be the right code. The details about this code are available in this [link](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/faq.html#how-do-i-send-a-message-to-a-specific-channel).

To send a message to specific channel

```
const channel = <client>.channels.cache.get('<id>');
channel.send('<content>');
```

To send a message to a specific user in DM

```
const user = <client>.users.cache.get('<id>');
user.send('<content>');
```

If you want to DM a user, please note that the bot and the user should have at least one server in common.

Hope this answer helps people who come here after version 12.

Answer (score 41):

You have an error in your `.send()` line. The current code that you have was used in an earlier version of the discord.js library, and the method to achieve this has been changed.

If you have a message object, such as in a `message` event handler, you can send a message to the channel of the message object like so:

```js
message.channel.send("My Message");
```

An example of that from a `message` event handler:

```js
client.on("message", function(message) {
  message.channel.send("My Message");
});
```

---

You can also send a message to a specific *channel*, which you can do by first getting the channel using its ID, then sending a message to it:

*(using async/await)*

```js
const channel = await client.channels.fetch(channelID);
channel.send("My Message");
```

*(using `Promise` callbacks)*

```js
client.channels.fetch(channelID).then(channel => {
  channel.send("My Message");
});
```

---

*Works as of [Discord.js](https://discord.js.org/) version 12*

Answer (score 8):

The top answer is outdated

New way is:

```
const channel = await client.channels.fetch(<id>);

await channel.send('hi')
```

To add a little context on getting the channel Id;
The list of all the channels is stored in the `client.channels` property.

A simple `console.log(client.channels)` will reveal an array of all the channels on that server.

Answer (score 3):

Below is the code to dm the user:

(In this case our message is not a response but a new message sent directly to the selected user.)

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: __dirname + '/.env.local' });

const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(client.users.get('ID_OF_USER').send("hello"));
});

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN);
```

Further documentation:

> https://github.com/AnIdiotsGuide/discordjs-bot-guide/blob/master/frequently-asked-questions.md#users-and-members

Answer (score 3):

There are four ways you could approach what you are trying to achieve, you can use `message.reply("Pong")` which mentions the user or use `message.channel.send("Pong")` which will not mention the user, additionally in `discord.js` you have the option to send embeds which you do through:

```
client.on("message", () => {
    var message = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setDescription("Pong") // sets the body of it
      .setColor("somecolor")
      .setThumbnail("./image");
      .setAuthor("Random Person")
      .setTitle("This is an embed")
    msg.channel.send(message) // without mention
    msg.reply(message) // with mention
})
```

There is also the option to dm the user which can be achieved by:

```
client.on("message", (msg) => {
msg.author.send("This is a dm")

})
```

See [the official documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/).

Comment: There are 3 ways. You can also DM the user.

Answer (score 1):

You can only send a message to a **channel**

```
client.on('message', function(message) {
 if (message.content === 'ping') {
  message.channel.send('pong');
 }
});
```

If you want to DM the user, then you can use the User.send() function

```
client.on('message', function(message) {
 if (message.content === 'ping') {
  message.author.send('pong');
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Types of ways to send a message:
DM'ing whoever ran the command:

```
client.on('message', function(message) {
 if (message.content === 'ping') {
  message.author.send('pong');
 }
});
```

Sends the message in the channel that the command was used in:

```
client.on('message', function(message) {
 if (message.content === 'ping') {
  message.channel.send('pong');
 }
});
```

Sends the message in a specific channel:

```
client.on('message', function(message) {
const channel = client.channels.get("<channel id>")
 if (message.content === 'ping') {
  channel.send("pong")
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Discord.js v14.13.0 code:

```
// Import d.js library
const { Client, Events } = require('discord.js');

// Your client
const client = new Client({...})

// Sending message
client.on(Events.MessageCreate, (msg) => {
if(msg.content.startsWith('ping') {
 return msg.reply('pong')
}
});

client.login(...)
```

Answer (score -1):

It's [`message.channel.send("content");`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextBasedChannel?scrollTo=send) since you're sending a message to the current channel.

Comment: Wrong link oops lol, https://discord.js.org/#/ is the link I meant to put

Comment: This is an almost 3 year old thread, but thanks nonetheless ;)

Comment: Didn't realize that lmao, no problem