# Discord.js sending a message to a specific channel

Tags: node.js, bots, send, discord.js

I'm failing to achieve something very simple. I can't send a message to a specific channel. I've browsed trough the documentation and similar threads on stack overflow.

> client.channels.get().send()

does NOT work. 
It is not a function.
I also do not see it as a method on the Channel class on the official documentation yet every thread I've found so far has told me to use that.

I managed to have the bot reply to a message by listening for a message and then using `message.reply()` but I don't want that. I want my bot to say something in a specific channel in `client.on('ready')`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You didn't provide any code that you already tested so I will give you the code for your ready event that will work!

```js
    client.on('ready', client => {
        client.channels.get('CHANNEL ID').send('Hello here!');
    })
```

Be careful that your channel id a string.

Let me know if it worked, thank you!

**2020 Jun 13 Edit:**

A Discord.js update requires the `cache` member of channels before the get method.

If your modules are legacy the above would still work. My recent solution works changing the send line as follows.

```js
        client.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL ID').send('Hello here!')
```

If you are using TypeScript, you will need to cast the channel in order to use the `TextChannel.send(message)` method without compiler errors.

```js
import { TextChannel } from 'discord.js';

( client.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL ID') as TextChannel ).send('Hello here!')
```

Comment: The issue was that there was both a voice channel and a text channel with the same name. I was trying to send a message to a channel that does is not able to receive messages. Your answer is correct and I've accepted it. thank you.

Comment: this worked for me.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60667394/9644424

Answer (score 7):

for v12 it would be the following:

```
  client.on('messageCreate', message => {
        client.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL ID').send('Hello here!');
    })
```

edit: I changed it to log a message.

Comment: I use Typescript and I get error `Property 'send' does not exist on type 'GuildChannel'.`

Comment: @callmenikk you need to cast it to a TextChannel as that only returns a "Channel" which doesn't contain the "Send" method.

Answer (score 2):

This will work for the newest version of node.js `msg.guild.channels.cache.find(i => i.name === 'announcements').send(annEmbed)`

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch) should work

```
client.channels.fetch('CHANNEL_ID')
    .then(channel=>channel.send('booyah!'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I send a message to a specific channel every time a message is deleted. This is helpful if you'd like to send the message without a channel ID.

```
client.on("messageDelete", (messageDelete) => {
  const channel = messageDelete.guild.channels.find(ch => ch.name === 'channel name here');
  channel.send(`The message : "${messageDelete.content}" by ${messageDelete.author} was deleted. Their ID is ${messageDelete.author.id}`);
});
```

Make sure to define it if you're not using messageDelete.