# how to send cron message to send to specific channel

Tags: javascript, cron, discord, discord.js

im still fairly new to javascript but im currently trying to make a cron message , it does work but now im trying to figure out how to send it to a specific channel

this is what i have so far

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var job = new CronJob('1 * * * * *', function () {
    message.channel.send('You will see this message every second');
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
job.start();
```

i have tried a few things but it either doesnt work or causes the code to crash

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js sending a message to a specific channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52258064/discord-js-sending-a-message-to-a-specific-channel)

Comment: its fine its just a test

Comment: `client.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL ID').send('Hello here!')` is the answer most likely. Please click the first link I sent to read more

Answer (score 0):

You can define a channel by finding one by name or id.

Find one by ID:

```
client.channels.cache.find(c => c.id === "id");
```

Find one by name:

```
client.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === "name")
```

Answer (score 0):

Marino's answer is technically correct but it's not what is recommended. You should do:

```
<client>.channels.cache.get("ID HERE")
```

or

```
<client>.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === "name")
```

it's best to use `.get` for IDs.

**Furthermore, your bot could get ratelimited if you send a message every second.**