# How to send a message to a specific mentioned channel?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to create a command that sends a `message` mentioning a `user` in a specific `channel`. The command is formatted like this:

> `:send @user #channel`

And this is the code I have:

```
let user = message.mentions.users.first().id;
        let channell = message.mentions.channels.first()
        channel.cache.get(`${channell}`).send(`<@${user}>`);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js sending a message to a specific channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52258064/discord-js-sending-a-message-to-a-specific-channel)

Comment: Hey, before you ask the next time please read [ask] :)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you want to do is getting the `channel` mentioned in the `command args` and the mentioned `user`:

```js
const channelID = args[1];
const mentionedUser = message.mentions.members.first();

if(!channelID) return message.reply('You need to provide a channelID!');
if(!mentionedUser) return message.reply(`Please use a proper member mention!`);

const targetChannel = await message.client.channels.fetch(channelID);
```

> In order to get the `ID` of a `channel` you have to activate `developer mode` in your Discord, then you can right click the `target channel` and hit `Copy channel ID`

*Alternatively you should be able to get a `channel` by it's name:*

```
const targetChannel = guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "Name of the channel");
```

After that is done you can now **send** your message to the destinated channel:

```
targetChannel.send(`Hello ${mentionedUser.toString()}`);
```

---

The reason why I'm using `.toString()` is because `message.mentions.members.first()` returns a `GuildMember`. If you look at the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=toString) you'll notice that `.toString()` automatically returns the user's `mention` instead of the `GuildMember` object.