# how to send a message to specific channel Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I need the code to send a message to a channel I have looked on stack overflow but there all too old and through up a error

Comment: please share your code to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There is a guide for this on the discord.js guide.](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/faq.html#how-do-i-send-a-message-to-a-specific-channel)

```js
const channel = <client>.channels.cache.get('<id>');
channel.send('<content>');
```

An improved version would be:

```js
<client>.channels.fetch('<id>').then(channel => channel.send('<content>'))
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at loginconsole (C:\Users\theen\Desktop\c3 SigServer\sigserv.js:30:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\theen\Desktop\c3 SigServer\sigserv.js:72:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)

Comment: @DrMeepso I have added an improved one-line version. The error you were getting was most likely caused by discord.js not getting the channel fast enough, but check that the ID is correct

Comment: @mmoomocow that's not it. He's doing them out the events. Also channels are always cached so you don't need to fetch them.

Answer (score 2):

At first you need to get the channel ID or Channel Name to do that

```js
/* You handle in command and have message */
// With Channel Name
const ChannelWantSend = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'Channel Name');
// With Channel ID
const ChannelWantSend = message.guild.channels.cache.get(channelId);
ChannelWantSend.send('Your Message');

/* If you start from root of your bot , having client */

// With Channel Name
const ChannelWantSend = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'Channel Name');
// With Channel ID
const ChannelWantSend = client.channels.cache.get(channelId);
ChannelWantSend.send('Your Message');

// In both case If ChannelWantSend is undefined where is a small chance that discord.js not caching channel so you need to fetch it

const ChannelWantSend = client.channels.fetch(channelId);
```

Comment: ReferenceError: message is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\theen\Desktop\c3 SigServer\sigserv.js:26:25)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)←[39m
←[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47←[39m

Comment: Where are you using that block of code. In a command or root of your bot

Comment: i hope this helps
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/524471091415089162/844816266107813888/unknown.png

Comment: Where is login console call please provide more code

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/524471091415089162/844821145576275998/unknown.png

Comment: @DrMeepso why is every thing outside the message event? Do them inside the message event. And ID is a snowflake, meaning it has to be a String. Take a deep look at the [guide](https://discordjs.guide/).

Comment: its ment to print out console out put form a Node JS server to a disocrd bot so i can look at things remotly

Comment: I updated my solution. And still not seeing where you call loginconsole function

Comment: here's where I'm calling it
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/524471091415089162/844836820205699082/unknown.png

Answer (score 0):

[Discord.js sending a message to a specific channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52258064/discord-js-sending-a-message-to-a-specific-channel)

Not sure if you have tested out this code yet, but it looks like this may answer your question?

I haven't tested this, but the thread I linked seems to have tested it as of June 2020!

Comment: TypeError: client.channels.get is not a function
    at loginconsole (C:\Users\theen\Desktop\c3 SigServer\sigserv.js:28:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\theen\Desktop\c3 SigServer\sigserv.js:70:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)

Comment: To use this function you must first login to the Discord client with 
'client.login('INSERT TOKEN HERE')' where the token being used is your bot token

Answer (score 0):

Shortly, I send message to specific channel like under.

```js
<client>.channels.cache.get("<channel_id>").send("SEND TEXT");
```

Under code piece is my own usage.
In my case, I save all of Direct Messages to my own channel.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

function saveDMToAdminChannel(message) {
  var textDM = `${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator} : ${message.content}`;
  client.channels.cache.get("0011223344556677").send(textDM);
  // "0011223344556677" is just sample.
}

client.on("message", async message => {
  if(message.author.bot) return;
  if(message.channel.type == 'dm') {
    saveDMToAdminChannel(message);
  }
});
```

In my own channel, DM's are saved like,

```
00:00 User1#1234 : Please fix bug
07:30 User2#2345 : Please fix bug!!
10:23 User3#3456 : Please fix bug!!!!
```