# Discord.JS Message in a specific Channel

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord.js

So i'm new to the whole Discord.JS thing and i am trying to figure out how to get the bot to write a message to the General Chat when a new person joins.

I have seen a lot of people doing it like this:

```
const channel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === channelName)
channel.send(message)
```

But this isnt working for me. Whenever i am trying to send a message with the `channel.send(message)` it gives me a error message.

I have also tried the version where you do it with the `client.channels.cache.get(<Channel-ID>)`

But this also didnt work for me.

Comment: Share the error message you receive.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code similar to the post: [how to send a message to specific channel Discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67614039/how-to-send-a-message-to-specific-channel-discord-js)

```js
<client>.channels.fetch('<id>').then(channel => channel.send('<content>'))
```

**Example**

```js
client.channels.fetch('922880975074127872')
.then(channel => channel.send(`Welcome, ${user}`))
```