# How do I send this message to another specific channel?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have this code which advertises to server admins and mods when someone tags an important user on the server (a user who should not be tagged).

Here's the code.

```js
client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if(message.author.bot || message.channel.type === `DM`) return;

    if(message.mentions.members.get(`332599069027598336`)){
        message.reply(`The user ${message.author} has mentioned ${message.mentions.members.get(`332599069027598336`).user.tag}`);
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this question help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52258064/discord-js-sending-a-message-to-a-specific-channel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to get the channel id.
`client.channels.cache.get('YOUR_CHANNEL_ID')`

Then you send it to a specific channel.
`` .send(`The user ${message.author} has mentioned ${message.mentions.members.get(`332599069027598336`).user.tag}`) ``

And your code should be like this:

````
client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if(message.author.bot || message.channel.type === `DM`) return;

    if(message.mentions.members.get(`332599069027598336`)) {
        client.channels.cache.get('YOUR_CHANNEL_ID').send(`The user ${message.author} has mentioned ${message.mentions.members.get(`332599069027598336`).user.tag}`)
    }
});```
````