# I can't send a message to a specific channel discordjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I was trying to send a message to a specific channel so I use the script below

```js
let msg = "I am a message"
clients.channels.cache.get("902208249099612170").send(msg)
```

but all I got were this error

```
clients.channels.cache.get("902208249099612170").send(msg)
                                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')
```

I have no idea why can't it send a message, I am using discord js v13, anyone has any idea what is the problem? Thanks

Comment: What intents does your client have?

Comment: Uhm, what is intent? I never heard of it before

Comment: When you make the `client`, you provide intents like `intents: xxx`

Answer (score 1):

The channel might not exist in the client's cache. Try `fetch`ing the channel instead:

```js
clients.channels.fetch("902208249099612170").then((channel) => channel.send(msg));

// Or with async/await
const channel = await clients.channels.fetch("902208249099612170");
channel.send(msg)
```

Comment: It didn't work either, plus it also somehow crash my bot

Comment: We need information on "didn't work", what errors do you get? Are you properly resolving the promise?

Comment: what I mean is that the async somehow log out my bot which forces me to re-log back in manually

Answer (score 1):

It means that the channel either doesn't exist or the bot can't see the channel/server the channel is in. Try catching it :

```js
let msg = "This is a message."
clients.channels.fetch("902208249099612170")
.then((channel) => channel.send(msg));
.catch(err => console.log("Could not find the channel."))
```

Comment: I tested it out and surprisingly it say could not find channel, but I tried other channels it still said it couldn't find the channel

Comment: @somekidplayingjs yea that means that the bot can't find the channel. Make sure the bot can see it and is in the server the channel is in (and ofc that it's a valid id)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the problem. Actually, there are multiple `client`s on the file and the one logged in to the bot isn't the one sending the message to the specific channel so that's why I am unable to send it. Sorry if I wasted you guys' time .

Lesson learned: When you want to send a message to a specific channel make sure the `client` is logged into the bot's token!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe forgot to listen to the `client.on('ready', client => {})` event?

If not, try checking the channel id and the bots permissions on this channel. The bot maybe doesn't have enough permission to view/send messages to the channel.

Try calling the send function without the cache. Although this should only work on legacy versions.

```
clients.channels.get("902208249099612170").send(msg)
```

References:

- [Discord.js sending a message to a specific channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52258064/discord-js-sending-a-message-to-a-specific-channel)

Comment: nope it didn't work, I got this error too `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')` tho