# TypeError: message.channel.sendMessage is not a function

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const request = require('request');
const PREFIX = "_"
const TOKEN = "XXXXX"
 
var bot = new Discord.Client();
 
bot.on("ready", function(){
    console.log("ready");
    bot.user.setActivity('_X 를 눌러 JOY를 표하세요!', {type: "PLAYING"}); 
})
 
bot.on("message", function(message) { 
    if (message.author.equals(bot.user)) return; 
 
    if(message.author.bot) return; 
 
    if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return; 
    var args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ")
 
    switch (args[0].toLowerCase()){
        case "X":
            message.channel.sendMessage("ㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋ")
            break;

        case "help": //만약 메시지가 {접두사}hello로 시작한다면
            message.channel.sendMessage("_X로 JOY를 표하세요") //안녕하세요라고 답변
            message.channel.sendMessage("_S로 침을 뱉으세요") //안녕하세요라고 답변
            message.channel.sendMessage("_T로 탈모 빔을 쏘세요") //안녕하세요라고 답변
            break;    //다음 스크립트가 실행 안되게 정지

        case "S": //만약 메시지가 {접두사}hello로 시작한다면
            message.channel.sendMessage("카아아아아아아아아악")
            message.channel.sendMessage("아아아아아아아아아악")
            message.channel.sendMessage("아아아아아아아아아악")
            message.channel.sendMessage("퇫")

        case "T": //만약 메시지가 {접두사}hello로 시작한다면
            MessageAttachment('https://imgur.com/a/OvoVKSu')

        default:
        message.channel.sendMessage("_help")
    }
});
 
bot.login(TOKEN)
```

it acts like
TypeError: message.channel.sendMessage is not a function
at Client. (C:\Users\qwerted\workspace\discord bot\app.js:44:29)

it brings error, but why?

this is weird

please tell me why

Comment: Looking at this thread over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45120618/send-a-message-with-discord-js Should you be using `message.channel.send('My Message')` ? If that doesn't help, can you console log `message.channel` to ensure it's picking up a valid channel?

Comment: Please reset your token, you just leaked it, I suggest you put your token in another file