# discord.js send message on specific channel

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I want to send a message on a specific channel. but the thing is my command should be like this **+post CHANNELID message** then it will post the message on this channel that I've put the id.
so can anyone help me to do that??

[example command I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9yj3.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send a message with Discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45120618/send-a-message-with-discord-js)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js sending a message to a specific channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52258064/discord-js-sending-a-message-to-a-specific-channel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simple actually. There are a few things you need to do.

1. Separate the arguments
2. Find channel with first argument (id)
3. Send message to the channel with content of other arguments joined with spaces

This is a working example of your command

```js
client.on("message", msg => {
  const args = msg.content.split(' ');
  const [, chanId, ...message] = args;
  const channel = msg.guild.channels.resolve(chanId);
  channel.send(message.join(" "))
})
```

Comment: Is it still not working? Have you resolved it?

Comment: No, I can't :( can you help me @MrMythical

Comment: Are you getting an error? Is nothing happening?