# Discord.js how to send embed to a specific channel

Tags: discord.js

How do i send embed to a specific channel.
dont mind the code below thats just my example on how i do it

```
id = client.channels.cache.get("id")

client.once('ready', () => {
    embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
            embed.setTitle('example')
            embed.setAuthor(client.user.tag)
            embed.setDescription('example')
    id.send({ embeds: [embed] })
})
```

Comment: Please, use the [search box above](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdiscord.js%5D+send+message+to+specific+channel) first.

Comment: I think that the example you have provided should do exactly what you are looking for :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send a message with Discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45120618/send-a-message-with-discord-js)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to fetch the channel.

```js
client.once('ready', () => {
  const channel = client.channels.cache.get('ID_HERE')
  let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('example')
  .setAuthor(client.user.tag)
  .setDescription('example')
  channel.send({ embeds: [ embed ] });
})
```

I've added `channel` into the ready event which should fix the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Just make it an embed

```js
client.on('ready', () => {
    client.channels.fetch('<channel id>')
    .then(channel => {
        channel.send("Hello here!");
    })
});
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question